# Updating an array element in javascript, splice push vs gets the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have here two ways on how to update array element.

```
var x = [{test: 'test', id: 1}, {test: 'test2', id: 2}, {test: 'test3', id: 3}];
```

**SPLICE PUSH**

```
for(var i in x) {
    if(x[i].id === 2) {
        x.splice(i, 1);
        x.push({test: 'updated', id: 3});
        break;
    }
}
```

**GETS THE VALUE**

```
for(var i in x) {
    if(x[i].id === 1) {
        x[i] = {test: 'updated', id: 3}
        break;
    }
}
```

I am not sure which one is much efficient like faster or less memory usage. Any advice is very much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Looping over every element of an array using *for..in* is not recommended unless you have a good reason for doing so and avoid inherited properties (unless you specifically want to visit them). Likely you should break from the loop once you find the element you're after unless you expect to find more than one. Both examples create duplicate elements with id of 3. With [*splice*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) you can replace the element in one go, no need for *splice* and *push*.

Comment: @RobG - okay my bad I added a `break` . . but yes regarding loop what would you recommend and going back to my question which is better **splice push** or **gets the value** ?

Comment: @RobG - I see . . so splice alone . . thanks a lot let me try

Comment: @RobG - thanks a lot it worked :) `for(var i in x) {
    if(x[i].id === 2) {
        x.splice(i, 1, {test: 'updated', id: 3});
        break;
    }
}` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` can be fairly expensive I ran some jsPerf tests and added another example https://jsperf.com/slice-push-vs-direct-update/1

[image: Benchmarks]

The slowest by far was splice - directly updating via iteration is about 2x as fast than slice, but creating an object map then directly accessing is the fastest by far!

My third test and the fastest option was this:

```
xMap[testID ] = {name: 'updated', id:3};
```

If you've got unique id's you can do this to convert the array to an object map

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    xMap[x[i].id] = x[i];
 }
```

My option is less memory efficient but MUCH faster - the map may however need to be updated if you're updating the data with new objects.

Update:
Changing to a `for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++){}` style loop makes things a LOT faster on Chrome! Splice is still slow but but the direct update comes to within 13% of the map.

Worth noting though that as data size increases these will also probably change so it may be worth while testing a data set of similar size to that you'll expect at the largest then benchmark that a little :)

Comment: -- wow this really clears up my question . .  thanks a lot . . I just bookmark the link you included . . thanks a lot mate . . :D

Comment: You're very welcome - I just added 2 tests - using a `for(var i =0; i < x.length; i++)` style loop brings the direct to within 10% of the map on Chrome so is also a viable option - it may be worth running the tests on a few other browsers too as results may vary but I think `splice` will always come up worst off :)

Comment: There have been many comparisons of array mutation methods over the years, (e.g. [*Native map vs. forEach appending vs. array looping*](https://jsperf.com/native-map-versus-array-looping) which shows negligible performance difference in Firefox). There are big variations between implementations, methods and scenarios. The bottom line is if performance isn't an issue (and it rarely is), the method that is most semantic and easiest to maintain has far higher significance than one that saves a few nanoseconds occassionally.

Comment: Well put @RobG I agree completely that ease of maintenance is usually the most important thing, optimization should come later if/when required.